# Java tool to remove warnings from code developed in java 1.4

Tags: java

I am working on a soucre code which was developed using java 1.4 but now we want to migrate it to java 6. I was able to compile it but there are tons of warnings related to use of java generics wherever we have made use of collections framework. It is possible to remove them by manually make changes to them, but I wanna know if is there any tool which can run on the source code and remove all the warnings by making necessary changes ot the code. Any help will be highly appreciated.
Cheers,
Nitin Ware

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse has an option to try to infer the type arguments for generic types. It's not fool-proof, but it's a start. It's available from the "Refactor" option in the context menu when you right-click inside the class's code.

Comment: Hi, I tried doing that way, but the it just supress the warning and dont make any changes to the code. I want a utility which can make necessary changes to my code and make it warning free.

Comment: I think maybe you commented on the wrong answer. The refactoring I mentioned doesn't suppress warnings.

Comment: Sorry, that comment was not for you, but still I tried the way you mentioned, but I want a utility that will run on my code and make necessary changes to the code and make it Java 5 compatible, which is done manually.

Answer (score 1):

Open your code with Eclipse, select your Package or Project and in the Refactor menu select **"Infer Generic Type Arguments"**. It will infer the types and correctly change almost all the warnings. Correct the last ones by hand.

Unfortunately sometimes the plugin sometimes crash while trying to do it. I'd also try to do it with IntelliJ IDE. **Edit:** I've tried with InteliJ and it also failed. Nothing happened after 2 days running. The newer eclipse almost worked, just crashed in 2 files. I'm using it in a very old project with non-standard paths. Maybe you'll have better luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could suppress warnings as a compiler option
-nowarn  or  -Xlint:none

see http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#options

Comment: but it just supress the warning and dont make any changes to the code. I want a utility which run on my code can make necessary changes to my code and make it warning free with out manually editing the code.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse you can set the "Target" JVM to 1.4, that should fix your problem in the editor.  I think you can also specify a target option to javac, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: I don't want to ignore the warnings, I want to remove them by making changes to the source code.